# How do you create an outer loop to read two separate mazes using the user's input C program

Tags: c

So we're supposed to read an input file from the user.
The input file contains the following:

- First Line: The number of mazes in the file
- Second Line: the first number is the number of nodes and the second number is the...
- ith Line: There will be lines that has the same format as the second line.
  These lines serve to tell you that you have reached the next maze. There are n such pairs of numbers, where n is the number indicated in the first line of the file.
- The Rest of the Lines: The rest of the lines are sets of three numbers containing the source, number of edges,destination, and edge/path cost.

The problem is, my program only reads the first half of the program. When it comes to the next "maze", it stops.

How to read both mazes in one go? Help please.
Here is the input file:

```
2  
16 15   
0 1 1   
1 5 1   
5 6 1   
6 7 1   
7 11 1   
11 10 1   
10 14 1   
14 13 1   
13 9 1   
14 15 1   
1 2 1   
2 3 1   
0 4 1   
4 8 1   
8 12 1   
16 15   
0 1 1   
1 2 1   
2 6 1   
6 7 1   
7 11 1   
11 15 1   
15 14 1   
14 13 1   
13 9 1   
9 5 1   
9 10 1   
2 3 1   
0 4 1   
4 8 1   
8 12 1
```

And here's my program:

```
fh = fopen("maze_test_small", "r");
chk_null_ptr(fh);

fscanf(fh, "%d",&nlines);
fscanf(fh, "%d %d", &nnodes, &nedges);
adjlist = (edgelist_t**) calloc(nnodes + 1, sizeof(edgelist_t *));
chk_null_ptr(adjlist);

for(i = 0; i < nnodes; i++)
{
    adjlist[i] = (edgelist_t *) calloc(1, sizeof(edgelist_t));
    chk_null_ptr(adjlist[i]);
    adjlist[i][0].cost = 0;
}

while(nedges--)
{
    fscanf(fh, "%d %d %d", &na, &nb, &wt);
    adjlist[na] = (edgelist_t *) realloc(adjlist[na], (adjlist[na]   [0].cost + 2) * sizeof(edgelist_t));
    adjlist[nb] = (edgelist_t *) realloc(adjlist[nb], (adjlist[na][0].cost + 2) * sizeof(edgelist_t));
    chk_null_ptr(adjlist[na]);
    chk_null_ptr(adjlist[nb]);
    adjlist[na][adjlist[na][0].cost + 1].dest = nb;
    adjlist[nb][adjlist[nb][0].cost + 1].dest = na;
    adjlist[na][adjlist[na][0].cost + 1].cost = wt;
    adjlist[nb][adjlist[nb][0].cost + 1].cost = wt;
    adjlist[na][0].cost++;
    adjlist[nb][0].cost++;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(fh, "%d",&nlines);` - not exactly accurate, that should be `nmazes`, and a loop running everything that follows that many times would probably get you want you want (assuming you change that code as well to account for more than one maze).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, but I'm having a problem with creating a code to account for more than one maze. What do I do then?

Answer (score 1):

You have not used a outer loop with `nlines`. That's why it is only reading a single maze.

You can do following thing:

```
for(i = 0; i < nlines; i++){
    // your code.
}
```

and if you do not need `nlines` anywhere else then,

```
while(nlines--){
    //your code
}
```

Comment: so should I do for(int=0; int<=nlines,int++) then proceed with the program? Sorry. I'm new at this thing. Any suggestions as to how to create an outer loop? Thanks xx

Comment: already tried it, caused a segmentation fault. any more suggestions? thanks btw xx

Comment: The segmentation fault could indicate that you forgot to update or recreate `adjlist`. When reading the first maze, it gets created with enough space for *that* one. What should happen when reading a next maze? Should it overwrite the first? Append? Create a new, independent `adjlist`?

Comment: Oh, so I really should create a new adjlist then? Because I think that this list is for just the first maze. So should I recreate another adjlist or should I just overwrite the first one? Thanks @Jongware !!!!

Comment: ?.. It really depends on what you ultimately need. "Overwrite": you'll only have the last maze 'in memory' (and you may need to resize `adjlist`); "append": all mazes will be in one long list; "new list": you'll need a list of `adjlist`s.

Comment: i need a new list. i've tried doing another adjlist but it's wrong. I'm stuck. Thanks btw @Jongware